# Missing Classes when scraping Google Pages with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am looking to scrape the audience review score for a specific movie.
i.e.
[image]

I have been looking to scrape this value using BS4, however I cannot seem to find this rating anywhere when scraping the URL. The critic rating (IMDb, RT, Meta) can be located, however the Google User Score is not there.

I used SerpApi to double check this, and the value doesn't show up on their either. I.e.
[image]

I am assuming this means that the Google User Score, may be updated using some other Script, and is not retrievable by these means. Could there possible be another method of retrieving this data?

Looking through the reponse using python shows no result either.

```
html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=shawshank+redemption&hl=en')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
}

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=shawshank+redemption&hl=en"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

liked = soup.find(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "span" and re.match(r"\d+% liked", tag.text)
)

print(liked.text.split()[0])
```

Prints:

```
96%
```

Comment: Could do the find as: `soup.find('span', text=re.compile('\d+% liked'))` (instead of the lambda)